# How to read json data in java and display particular output from key value pair

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have json file with data

```
 ( "date" : "2019-1-2"
   "Group" : "xyz"
   "Bookname" : "harrypotter"
   "Url" : "https:dhdudgussisk"
),
( " date" : " 2015-2-3"
  " Group" : "qbc"
  "Bookname" : "happy"
  "Url" : "https://hdhdjdksksksks"
)
```

The code has to be in java written in a way such that when I change the input bookname value the output should display its respective url....some one please help me solve this

Comment: Your question is not clear, you want to search based on bookname?

Comment: As a new memeber, you may want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes If search of harrypitter it should give the url as output ...

Answer (score 0):

Lets hope we understood you right, you want to read out of an json
with key-value method.

I think what could help you is knowing how to properly parse an json to java.

[How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of libraries providing this. You should explore the internet before you asked a question which was answered many times and it is not hard to find a relevant tutorial.

For example, the Jackson library can be used there.

[Intro to the Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).